# how to call this constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The class `CameraPerspAsym` extends `CameraPersp` and has this constructor:

```
CameraPerspAsym( int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight, float fov, float nearPlane, float farPlane ) 
: CameraPersp(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, fov, nearPlane, farPlane),
mLensShiftX(0.0f),
mLensShiftY(0.0f){};
```

(I've put it in 4 lines for easier reading)

AFAIK it seems the params `( int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight etc ... )` are passed to the base class. But what about the `mLensShiftX(0.0f)` ?

So how should I call this contructor?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with a good C++ book that covers the basics of inheritance.

Comment: Because it does not show any research effort and it is not terribly useful.

Comment: It is also not a place to have an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to worry about supplying arguments for the child-class's constructor, in this case `int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight, float fov, float nearPlane, float farPlane`. How it passes those arguments to its parent, or uses them to initialize its members, is an implementation details and hidden from you.

The `mLensShiftX(0.0f), mLensShiftY(0.0f)` is the class explicitly initializing two instance variables with the value `0.0f`, and you don't need to do anything when using the class `CameraPerspAsym` to allow that to happen, neither can you specify alternate values. You'll have to use the interface the class exposes to alter those values after the constructor has run.

Answer (score 1):

Call it like you would call any constructor.  With actual parameters whose types match the types of the formal parameters or that can freely convert to the types of the formal parameters.

`mLensShiftX` and `mLensShiftY` are apparently defaulted to floating point 0.0; thus I would assume that you can mutate those values via some method on the object.